# how do i pretty print a JsonSlurper.parse (url) result of type groovy.json.internal.LazyMap

Tags: json, groovy

I have a piece of code that calls google geocode API and returns Json result, like this

```
    def response = new JsonSlurper().parse (url.toURL())
```

however the return type is actually of type groovy.json.internal.LazyMap.

when i try and pretty print that with the following

```
    def res = JsonOutput.prettyPrint (response.toString())
```

i get an error like this 

`Caught: groovy.json.JsonException: Lexing failed on line: 1, column: 2, while reading 'r', no possible valid JSON value or punctuation could be recognized.
groovy.json.JsonException: Lexing failed on line: 1, column: 2, while reading 'r', no possible valid JSON value or punctuation could be recognized.
    at org.softwood.Geolocation.Geocoder.completeLatLong(Geocoder.groovy:29)
    at org.softwood.Geolocation.Geocoder$completeLatLong.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.softwood.Geolocation.TestGeoScript.run(TestGeoScript.groovy:13`

the actual toString() on that lazy maps gives - which doesn't put quotes round the string results - presumably why it wont parse correctly

`{results=[{address_components=[{long_name=South Close, short_name=South Cl, types=[route]}, {long_name=Ipswich, short_name=Ipswich, types=[locality, political]}, {long_name=Ipswich, short_name=Ipswich, types=[postal_town]}, {long_name=Suffolk, short_name=Suffolk, types=[administrative_area_level_2, political]}, {long_name=United Kingdom, short_name=GB, types=[country, political]}, {long_name=IP4 2TH, short_name=IP4 2TH, types=[postal_code]}], formatted_address=South Cl, Ipswich, Suffolk IP4 2TH, UK, geometry={bounds={northeast={lat=52.068566, lng=1.1667458}, southwest={lat=52.0672503, lng=1.1658643}}, location={lat=52.06789149999999, lng=1.1663008}, location_type=GEOMETRIC_CENTER, viewport={northeast={lat=52.0692571302915, lng=1.167654030291502}, southwest={lat=52.0665591697085, lng=1.164956069708498}}}, place_id=ChIJr3u-xXyf2UcRJF_b9Yp2_Ng, types=[route]}, {address_components=[{long_name=IP4 2TH, short_name=IP4 2TH, types=[postal_code]}, {long_name=South Close, short_name=South Cl, types=[route]}, {long_name=Ipswich, short_name=Ipswich, types=[locality, political]}, {long_name=Ipswich, short_name=Ipswich, types=[postal_town]}, {long_name=Suffolk, short_name=Suffolk, types=[administrative_area_level_2, political]}, {long_name=United Kingdom, short_name=GB, types=[country, political]}], formatted_address=South Cl, Ipswich, Suffolk IP4 2TH, UK, geometry={bounds={northeast={lat=52.068475, lng=1.1673588}, southwest={lat=52.0666643, lng=1.1643497}}, location={lat=52.0676263, lng=1.1658643}, location_type=APPROXIMATE, viewport={northeast={lat=52.0689186302915, lng=1.1673588}, southwest={lat=52.0662206697085, lng=1.1643497}}}, place_id=ChIJ7asZ3Xyf2UcRavs18W4IXUM, types=[postal_code]}], status=OK}`

query - given the returned result - how to you 'convert it' into a form that prettyPrint will parse and render ?

Answer (score 9):

Using JsonBuilder seems like the easiest route to take here:

```
String json = new JsonBuilder(response).toPrettyString()
```

Should give you the pretty json you're after?

Comment: way to go - that did the job as required.  might put a request in GDK to add as a method on the groovy.json.internal.LazyMap.  its a bit fiddly 'knowing' to rebuild the json using the builder put to call toPrettyString.  I cant be the only numpty caught out by this one

Answer (score 4):

Also possible using `JsonOutput`:

```
import groovy.json.JsonOutput;

def json = JsonOutput.toJson([foo: 'bar', baz: [1]])
assert json == '{"foo":"bar","baz":[1]}'
def pretty = JsonOutput.prettyPrint(json)
```